# A function $f$ such that $f(0) > 0$, $f'(0) = 0$, and as $x$ goes to infinity, $f(x)$ approaches $0$?

Tags: functions

I have been playing around with many functions without much success. 
The function should have a single inflection point if possible.

[Drawn on a Whiteboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRkLp.jpg)

Comment: Some possible inspiration [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function).

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect

Comment: Example: $y=exp(-x^2).$

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that came to my mind is $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ which has derivative $f'(x)=-\frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2}$ and we have:

$$f(0)=1>0$$
$$f'(0)=0$$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)= 0$$

Comment: Oh the witch of agnesi :)

Comment: That's the one you were looking for! :)